# Excluding/Including items from one array based on values from another

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have two arrays, one containing hashes, the other integers.  They look like this (samples):

```
mainArray[0] = {"ID" => 23, "NAME" => "SALLY"}
mainArray[1] = {"ID" => 34, "NAME" => "BILL"}

idArray[0] = 432
idArray[1] = 34
```

I want to filter `mainArray` so that only the entries in it whose ID values are in `idArray` make the cut.  How can I best do this?  I don't mind making a new array if that helps.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking for help with code, it's important to provide the minimum input data that works with the problem, your expected output, *AND* a minimal example of the code you're asking about. Without that it looks like you're asking us to write code for you. Your input data is a hash, not an array, and while you say it's an array you need to supply an example, not make us create one for you. The closer you are to your actual situation, the closer our answers will fit.

Comment: Can multiple hashes have the same ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
mainArray.find_all { |a| idArray.include?(a["ID"]) }
# => [{"ID"=>34, "NAME"=>"BILL"}]
```

Comment: While this will work, it will slow down as `mainArray` and/or `idArray` grow in size.

Answer (score 1):

If the `ID` values in the hashes are always going to be unique, you can do this, which will run extremely fast:

```
main_array = [
  {"ID" => 23, "NAME" => "SALLY"},
  {"ID" => 34, "NAME" => "BILL"}
]

id_array = [432, 34]

main_hash = main_array.map{ |h| [h['ID'], h['NAME']] }.to_h
main_hash.values_at(*id_array).compact # => ["BILL"]
```

The idea is to turn the main array into a hash, using the ID fields as the keys and names as values. Hash lookups are *much* faster than doing the same with arrays, especially when you have to look inside each one.

Your coding style is not idiomatic for Ruby. We use snake_case for_variables_and_methods_because_it_is_easier toReadThanCamelCase. We use CamelCase for classes and modules. We use UPPERCASE for constants. Follow these conventions otherwise you'll catch significant grief if you're programming professionally. More information is available at:

- https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide
- https://github.com/styleguide/ruby

Answer (score 1):

```
h = mainArray.to_enum.with_object({}){|e, h| h[e["ID"]] = e["NAME"]}
idArray.map{|e| h[e]}.compact
```